# awk script to parse output of ps command

Tags: awk

I have never worked on programming languages before.
I am learning C and unix architecture by refering online links.
I got small exercise to write awk script to parse output of ps command.
please help and please provide me the names of best books for C & awk scripting.

Comment: The best C book is "The C Programming Language" (2nd edition) By Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.

Comment: The canonical AWK book is [The AWK Programming Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/awkbook/) by the authors of the language (Aho - A, Weinberger - W, and Kernighan - K). Also [sed & awk](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922259) or [Effective AWK Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000707/) from O'Reilly are good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets say you want to list just the command column(8th column) from the `ps -ef` output, you can do:

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $8}'
```

Comment: You'll get plenty of resource online like http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html Also you can refer to the awk questions on stackoverflow here.

Comment: This would only print the executable file without the arguments. For example, if the command was "java -jar yourFile.jar" you would only get "java".

Comment: `awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8="" ;}1' | sed -e 's/^ *//'`